# expression must be a modifiable lvalue by using template class

Tags: c++

I have a template vector class. This is how a part of it looks like:

```
template<class Type>
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector(int size)
    {
        MyTime = new Type[size];
        m_size = size;
        m_current = -1;
    }

void set(int i,Type &data)
{
    data[i]=Mytime[i];
}

private:
    Type* MyTime;
    int m_size;
    int m_current;
};
```

Then i wish to use the set method above to set the value into a string "records".

```
    for(int i=0 ; i<count ; i++)
{
    records.set(i)=dateList.get(i)+timeList3.get(i);
}
```

But it gives me two errors:
1. too few argument in function call.
2. expression must be a modifiable lvalue.
Both errors appear at the records.set(i).

The declaration of "records" is:

```
Vector<string> records(100);
```

This makes me quite confuse. May I know how to solve it?

Comment: Please show the declaration of `records`

Comment: The declaration of records is: Vector<string> records(100)

Comment: what is the definition of get ,  data[i]=Mytime[i]; should be  Mytime[i]=data[i] right?

Comment: The definition of get is : Type get(int i){ return Mytime[i];}. Just pass the value the those list.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `records.set(i)=dateList.get(i)+timeList3.get(i);` is supposed to be this:

```
records.set(i, dateList.get(i) + timeList3.get(i));
```

**too few argument in function call.** - In your example you only pass `i`, meanwhile there are two arguments required to `set`

**expression must be a modifiable lvalue** - `set()` return void, it's not a method that returns a *modifiable lvalue*.

Meanwhile, you `vector` class does some weird things. This is a basic template vector class.

```
template <typename T>
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector(int size) : data(new T[size]) {}

    void Set(int index, const T& val) { data[index] = val; }
    T Get(int index) { return data[index]; }

private:
    T* data;
}
```